# Erasure of type fields

Tags: scala, type-erasure

```
abstract class Handler {
  type Message

  def handleAny(msg: Any) {
    if (msg.isInstanceOf[Message]) handle(msg.asInstanceOf[Message]) // fix me!
  }

  def handle(msg: Message)
}

class StringHandler extends Handler {
  override type Message = String

  def handle(msg: Message) { println(s"handling: $msg") }
}

val h = new StringHandler
h.handleAny("ahoj")
h.handleAny(true)
```

---

```
warning: abstract type Handler.this.Message is unchecked since it is
 eliminated by erasure
                if(msg.isInstanceOf[Message]) handle(msg.asInstanceOf[Message])
                                   ^
one warning found
handling: ahoj
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at Main$$anon$1$StringHandler.handle(typeProblem.scala:11)
        at Main$$anon$1$Handler.handleAny(typeProblem.scala:5)
```

**How to change the snippet** (without changing interface or replacing type field with type parameter) to work as expected, which is **to handle only messages specified by the type field**?

I'm looking for a solution which can be applied to the parent abstract class rather than polluting all children.

I also tried to use a `match` and it behaves exactly same. Or is this kind of thing impossible with type fields (I thought they are more powerful than type parameters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One usually uses a match and in your case, as you do not want to add any type parameters you will have to specify a `ClassTag` (I think).

Something along the lines of:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

abstract class Handler {
  type Message <: Any
  implicit val tag: ClassTag[Message]

  def handleAny(msg: Any): Unit = {
    msg match {
      case tag(message) =>
        handle(message)
      case _ =>
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Argmument MUST BE a 'Message' but $msg is not!")
    }
  }

  def handle(msg: Message): Unit
}

object StringHandler extends Handler {
  override type Message = String
  // lazy is important here!
  implicit lazy val tag: ClassTag[Message] = ClassTag(classOf[String])

  def handle(msg: Message): Unit =  { println(s"handling: $msg") }
}


StringHandler.handleAny("ahoj")
StringHandler.handleAny(true)
```